# SQL how to create a count that moves to the next number after a certain number of rows and then loops back to start over

Tags: sql, row-number, dense-rank

I need to be able to create a column that has a count up to 3 but will provide numbers 1-3 three times each before starting over again.

My current code below only counts up to 3 and starts over. I need it to count each number 3 times then start over

```
Select personid, taskid, 1 + ( (row_number() over (order by personid) - 1) % 3) AS taskNumber2 from taskTable
```

Table in DB:

```
Personid taskid
1        1 
1        2
2        3
2        4
2        5
3        6
4        7
4        8
5        9
5        10
5        11
```

Expected Results:

```
Personid taskid numberCount
1        1      1
1        2      1
2        3      1
2        4      2
2        5      2
3        6      2
4        7      3
4        8      3
5        9      3
5        10     1
5        11     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to determine your value. Let the row number be `x`. Since you are repeating ervery 9th entry, take modulo 9. For easier calculating, subtract 1 before this. So now 0-2 -> 1, 3-5 -> 2, 6-8 -> 3. Thus devide by 3 (integer division) and add 1.

```
SELECT personid, taskid,
    ((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY personid) - 1) % 9) / 3 + 1 AS taskNumber2
FROM taskTable
ORDER BY personid
```

Also note, that I added the same `ORDER BY` clause to the whole statement as in the window function, thus assuring correct ordering (at least if this ordering is not ambigious, e.g. it is unique, perhaps a primary key)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.